# ErrorMessage in Rsuite cant overflow in table row

Tags: css, reactjs, rsuite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlCcs.png)
Look at my picture.
I have an issue like this.
I cant find out my way to show my error tooltip over my row in my table.
Someone have met this trouble before.
Any suggest for me?

I have try to set overflow property is auto in every single html tag inner my table row but nothing happen.
I still try to set z-index of this tooltip but still got nothing.

This is my example about this:
[1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/errormessage-not-overflow-in-table-row-4y6m2b?file=/index.js

Comment: zIndex on element needs to setting up position property.  please add css and component code to your question

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/errormessage-not-overflow-in-table-row-4y6m2b?file=/index.js
thank you for your reply
checkout my code in codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit your style.css file :

```
@import "rsuite/dist/rsuite.css";

#root {
  padding: 10px;
}

.rs-table-row,
.gridcell,
.rs-table-cell ,
.rs-table-cell-content {
  overflow: unset !important;
}
```